# What's a good substitute for the TD62783AFNG?

Tags: led, driver

According to its datasheet, the TD62783AFNG is an 8-channel high-voltage high source-current driver. It is a Darlington arrangement that can source (not sink) up to half an amp through a pin. What similar chips are available?

http://www.semicon.toshiba.co.jp/docs/datasheet/en/LinearIC/TD62783AFNG_en_datasheet_091116.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Texas Instruments TLC59213A](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/tlc59213a.html) is similar, but not as high voltage. Other than that, it looks like a good fit.

Comment: Thanks! That chip looks useful. A little more expensive but with a more desirable (lower) high-level input voltage.